# How to always get the full number or rounded up (always) number c#

Tags: c#

If I have a `decimal` value I would like to return it's full number or next number (always round up) if there are any values in the decimal.

ie:

```
150.2148 ... returns 151
150.0000 ... returns 150
```

Which math function does this?

Comment: `Math.Ceiling` should do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Math.Ceiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ceiling(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you are looking for, it has an overload for accepting decimal.

> "Returns the smallest integer greater than **or equal** to the specified
>   number."

To verify:

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling(150.2148M)); //prints 151
Console.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling(150.0000M)); //prints 150
```

Just in case:

`150.0000M` means decimal literal with value `150.0000`. `M` in C# is used to denote the decimal type of the literal. It's not the most common literal type, so this note can be useful.